# GUI for "svn blame" with a slider for history

Tags: eclipse, svn, slider, history, blame

Does anyone know UI tool (Eclipse plugin would be great, but any other, for Linux/Windows is acceptable) that allows to see difference of some part of code, but also allows switch between revisions quickly, e.g. by using slider.

Comment: If you are also looking for a GUI tool other than an eclipse plugin, it might be helpful to name your platform.

Answer (score 2):

I like the `Team` -> `Show Annotation...` functionality. It colors the left side of the editor and groups changed lines by color. When you hover over one section you get the commit details (revision/author/date/comment).

Comment: Yes, I like it too, but you cannot switch between revisions quickly staying on the same for part of code. ( PS: I mean something like history scrolling in Google Wave, RIP)

Comment: @NMI: Pressing Ctrl+Alt+A opens the configuration dialog. Here you can select a starting or an ending revision. If that's not quick for you I'm really interested in your use case.

Comment: Use case: 1) open some file. 2) scroll (or select?) to some line. 3) Here you want to see how this part was changing in previous revisions (and, probably, who changed it). You just need to have slider ( or history list, but slider is more convenient) and see changes for exactly this part. It may be replacing of entire file content with staying on the same line. Without opening additional pages.

Comment: Again - good example is the feature from Google Wave, when you can scroll history of changes.

Comment: Perforce does have it, too, and I really miss the feature, now that I'm back to using SVN (w/ tortoise) in my current job. As well as some other super neat features I only learned to love when I "lost" them!

Answer (score 1):

I've used SVN time lapse view with some success.
http://code.google.com/p/svn-time-lapse-view/

It would be nice if Tortoise SVN blame included this history slider feature.